List all mounts in Command Prompt
How do I list all mounted filesystems, including those that use special interfaces like WinFsp and those mounted at folder paths, using Command Prompt? Note, that I am not looking to list "available drives" as in this question.

Doesn't mountvol do it for you?

Can you explain what you mean by "filesystems"? In Windows this usually means something a drive letter is assigned to, an "available drive". You say you are not talking about "available drives" but you don't clarify what you mean otherwise. Please EDIT your post to clarify this.
